# How do I recover Outlook E-mails after uninstalling it?

Tags: outlook, office-2007

A friend of mine has uninstalled Outlook 2007. It wasn't working for her but she kept it as an E-mail repository, a POP3 E-mail nonetheless that was going back years. The hosting guys are not keeping them.

I understand there is a chance to recover them by locating the Profile file/folders somewhere but I am not finding any concrete information out there.

I am not with her now so I can't give you the specifics but asking in advance in case someone can help.

The specs are:

- Outlook 2007
- Windows 10

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try searching for pst files on the machine. If found, you can add it as an additional store in Outlook and get access to the emails from the storage.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot I didn't update this question. I had to install Office 2019 in order to retrieve it and then thought the PST file much be on the machine in order for Outlook to be able to retrieve the mails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Office 2019 and the E-mails were there. It turns out that uninstalling Office doesn't remove the PST files, which I couldn't find before (am a Mac user and didn't know the folder was hidden).

Anyhow, I hope this helps someone some day.